# CakePHP 2.0 ACL - updating the user record results in ARO error

Tags: cakephp, acl

I am using ACL in CakePHP 2.3.0-RC1

When I update a user field (optin to marketing) I get an error:

```
AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by "Array ( [Aro0.model] => User[Aro0.foreign_key] => 4 ) "
```

I think that this is related to saving the user.  I can't find anything in the manual about how to work around this.

Here is the method snipped from the Controller:

```
$me = $this->Session->read('Auth.User');
// don't use the session to display, because they might have subscribed/unsubscribed
$user = $this->User->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$me['id'])));
$optin = ! $user['User']['optin'];
$data  = array(
                'User' => array(
                            'id'    => $me['id'],
                            'optin' => $optin
                        )
            );
if ( $this->User->save($data) ) 
{
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Subscription status has been amended'));
} 
else 
{
     $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
}
$this->redirect(array('action'=>'account'));
```

After redirecting I get the ARO error.

Comment: Never used Aro but if you do a `debug($aro);` on the page is the array containing any invalid data?

Comment: Looks like the user does not have an acl entry for that object.

Comment: @ColbyGuyer is correct, the user is missing an ARO record and therefore your ACL check throws that error when trying to find it. Usually on ACL setups, the User model has an afterSave that adds the ARO. Make sure that's happening.

Comment: Thanks @ColbyGuyer and jeremyharris ... I had the user model set up as a requester but actually intended to use role based auth on a related "group" model. I set up the parent node but neglected to take out the Acts As Requester from the user model.  Commenting that out worked a charm - I don't actually require an ARO object for the user (just the group).  Please make your comment an answer so that I can accept.

Comment: @Andy : You should write the information about taking out Acts As as the official answer to this question, because I think it probably applies to a lot of cases. The Cake tutorial tells you to put it there, but it isn't necessary if you're only doing group-level ACL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments I'm just writing this up as the answer.

I had the user model set up as a requester but actually intended to use role based auth on a related "group" model.

I set up the parent node but neglected to take out the Acts As Requester from the user model.

Commenting that out worked a charm - I don't actually require an ARO object for the user (just the group) and it was there just because the Cake tutorial includes it.

Answer (score 0):

The current tutorial (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html) says to disable the requester directive

```
public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester', 'enabled' => false));
```

in the user model in case you intend to have group-only ACL. And you have to implement the bind method:

```
public function bindNode($user) {
return array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => $user['User']['group_id']);
```

}

This worked for me.